# No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns problem in VB.NET but in C# No problem

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview, binding

If I run the vb.net project then a problem appears in datagridview whereas if I run the C# project there is no problem in datagridview . I'm using Kimtoo.BindingProvider.

Thanks

[image: Capture18-11-2022]

add info exception detail from problem

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.AddInternal(Boolean newRow, Object[] values)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.Add()
       at Kimtoo.BindingProvider.DGVBindingProvider.Bind[T](DataGridView grid, IEnumerable`1 items, Boolean append)
```

adding code in the post so that it is easier to find out the solution to the problem

```
'In code VB.NET
Public Class Payment
        <PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement>
        Public Property Id() As Integer

        <ForeignKey(GetType(Goal), OnDelete := "CASCADE")>
        Public Property GoalId() As Integer

        Public Property Description() As String = ""
        Public Property Amount() As Double

        Public Property CreatedAt() As DateTime = DateTime.Now
'binding features for Kimtoo Toolkit

        Public Function GetGoal() As Goal
            Return New Goal() With {.Name = "New Car"}
        End Function

        Public Function GetGoalBadge() As DataGridViewBadge
            Return New DataGridViewBadge() With {
                .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 212, 99),
                .ForeColor = Color.White,
                .Value = "New House"
            }
        End Function

        Public Function GetBalance() As Double
            Return 257
        End Function

        Public Function GetBalanceBar() As DatagridViewProgressBar
            Return New DatagridViewProgressBar() With {
                .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(34, 63, 58),
                .FillColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 212, 99),
                .Value = 60
            }
        End Function

        Public Function GetAvatar() As DataGridViewAvatar
            Return New DataGridViewAvatar() With {
                .Value = Me.Description.ToString(),
                .Icon = Image.FromFile("money.png")
            }
        End Function
End Class
Public Sub New()
            If Me.IsInDesignMode() Then
                Return
            End If
            InitializeComponent()
            LoadData()
        End Sub
Private Sub LoadData()
            Dim payments As New List(Of Payment)()
            'todo - add testing data
            For i As Integer = 0 To 9
                payments.Add(New Payment() With {
                    .Description = $"payment {i + 1}",
                    .Amount = 1000,
                    .GoalId = 0
                })
            Next i

            'bind data using kimtoo toolkit
            grid.Bind(payments)
        End Sub
```

```
'In code C#
 public class Payment
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof(Goal), OnDelete = "CASCADE")]
        public int GoalId { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; } = "";
        public double Amount { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
//binding features for Kimtoo Toolkit
        public Goal GetGoal()
            => new Goal()
            {
                Name = "New Car"
            };

        public DataGridViewBadge GetGoalBadge()
       => new DataGridViewBadge()
       {
           BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 212, 99),
           ForeColor = Color.White,
           Value = "New House"
       };

        public double GetBalance()
            => 257;

        public DatagridViewProgressBar GetBalanceBar()
             => new DatagridViewProgressBar()
             {
                 BackColor = Color.FromArgb(34, 63, 58),
                 FillColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 212, 99),
                 Value = 60 //todo
             };

        public DataGridViewAvatar GetAvatar()
         => new DataGridViewAvatar()
         {
             Value = this.Description.ToString(),
             Icon = Image.FromFile("money.png")
         };
}
public PagePayments()
        {
            if (this.IsInDesignMode()) return;
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadData();
        }
private void LoadData()
        {
            List<Payment> payments = new List<Payment>();
            //todo - add testing data
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                payments.Add(new Payment()
                {
                    Description = $"payment {i + 1}",
                    Amount = 1000,
                    GoalId = 0, //todo,
                });
            }

            //bind data using kimtoo toolkit
            grid.Bind(payments);
        }
```

I want the solution to run on the vb.net project without the datagridview problem.

Comment: @KimTooFlex ,maybe you know the problem because you are the developer of kimtoo.bindingprovider

Comment: Have you confirmed that the declaration/initialization code for the datagridview is the same in both VB and C#?  As an extreme fallback, you might try comparing the IL from VB and C# to see if there are any significant differences---there aren't any obvious source-level differences.

Comment: @Craig , Thank you for your reply. I have updated the code in my post maybe you can provide a solution